# specify sort string in index see entry

Tags: indexing, sorting

How is it possible to specify a sort string inside a `see` index entry? 
I am using `makeindex` and TeXLive 2014.

For example, say I have a primary entry where the sort string is plain `B` and the displayed entry is bold **B**:

```
\index{B@\textbf{B}}
```

Now I want to add a `see` entry, but of course this doesn't work:

```
\index{A@\textbf{A}|see{B@\textbf{B}}}
```

Currently I write the `see` entry with plain `B`:

```
\index{A@\textbf{A}|see{B}}
```

but that isn't really correct.

Comment: did you try `\index{A@\textbf{A}|see{\textbf{B}}}`?  (i can't test this just now, hence a comment, not an answer.)

Comment: Thanks @barbarabeeton, can't believe I didn't try that. Forest vs trees.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

an "unsorted" cross-reference works:

```
\index{A@\textbf{A}|see{\textbf{B}}}
```